# Auto Generate Database Diagram MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, diagram

I'm tired of opening Dia and creating a database diagram at the beginning of every project. Is there a tool out there that will let me select specific tables and then create a database diagram for me based on a MySQL database? Preferably it would allow me to edit the diagram afterward since none of the foreign keys are set...

Here is what I am picturing diagram-wise (please excuse the horrible data design, I didn't design it. Let's focus on the diagram concept and not on the actual data it represents for this example ;) ):

[image: diagram]
[see full size diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnN2O.png)

Comment: you can use phpmyadmin designer

Comment: You can also use in-build [database designer](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-designer.html#header) in dbForge Studio for MySQL for this purpose.

Comment: DBVisualizer has a clean presentation of tables in its References section.  It shows tables with all the relations neatly stacked and reader-friendly.

Answer (score 440, accepted):

Try MySQL Workbench, formerly DBDesigner 4:

http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/

This has a "Reverse Engineer Database" mode:

Database -> Reverse Engineer

[image]

Comment: Takes "7 days or longer" to be approved for the download...? :/

Comment: @James: Still works fine, click on Download Workbench 5.2.16 (upper right corner), then on "No Thanks, just take me to the downloads" and it should work - at least for Windows, haven't tried any other platform.

Comment: @michael-stum I find MySQL workbench very helpful, but find that the reverse engineer database function doesn't automatically link the tables so the tables still requires rearranging.

Comment: My tables have non-standard key field names. The reverse engineering feature did not work at all. Doesn't really matter to me. I find it problematic to link the tables to the right fields manually though. Overall its not really commercial grade app. Anyone find it useful let us know.

Comment: Note that this is in the Ubuntu repositories as mysql-workbench.

Comment: I have 237 tables. it seems to work and generate the diagram but it can't do the auto-layout and then it crashes.

Comment: I don't usually have any problems with the program-- then again I started being better at normalizing my tables and not doing anything 'creative' when I started using it. The diagrams it creates are nice. The gripe I have with it is that I have to move every table representation into position, everything at the very least needs a tweak.  
That being said, for quick and dirty no rearranging just for me, I use SchemaSpy.  
Workbench is pretty, professional looking, and great for giving to people that need superficial pretty. The caveat is that it takes time and why I use other tools for me.

Comment: This is wonderful... I just done 2 assignments for college at once :) Wish I knew about this a couple weeks ago!

Comment: Dude this saved me hours of working. Had a intense db that I needed some documentation for and a visual chart for those who didnt understand things. Took minutes. THANK YOU!

Comment: You'll find this in "Database -> Reverse Engineer" menu under the DB tabs.

Comment: You don't even need to connect to the database for this. Export your MySQL database using the "structure only" option. In MySQL Workbench go to  "File -> New Model", then "File -> Import -> Reverse Engineer MySQL Create Script..." and check the "Place imported objects on a diagram" box.

Comment: I'm working on a database with 545 tables and 16 views. It seems like this layout is limited to a physical paper size and doesn't seem to like anything like 100"x200". Is there a way to layout very large diagrams?

Comment: this looks like an overkill to me

Comment: @jocull, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4933000/82216

Answer (score 67):

I've recently started using https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy . It strikes me as having a good balance between usability and simplicity. (GraphViz now optional)

Comment: I am using it too it's great tool, here how configure it  http://progrnotes.blogspot.com/2011/05/auto-generate-databaseer-diagram-mysql.html

Comment: schemaspy creates interractive schema (see http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/) that is simply static html files that can be stored and used everywhere.

MySQL Workbench do not create interractive schema (only image files or pdf) and on top of that do not automatically and nicely rearrange the tables.

For automation (nightly builds create updated schema), schemaspy fits the bill too as it is entirely command-line.

Comment: +1 This was the only tool that did what I wanted: generate DB documentation at release time automatically.

Comment: It strikes me with amount of errors I am getting and installations I need to do to make it work on Linux.

Comment: @DamirOlejar you need to  have a stable graphviz (alias dot) release installed, I do not recommend compiling it yourself. this will lead to a different version which does not recognize pngs and thus will fail schemaspy. / anyway, once it's set up, this tool is pretty neat +1

Comment: @Blahurim, +1 for a reply, however a lot of time has passed since and I have no time to test it. Thanks, I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: There's also SchemaCrawler. It's an and up-to-date alternative to SchemaSpy.
https://www.schemacrawler.com/

Answer (score 26):

On a Mac, [SQLEditor](http://www.malcolmhardie.com/sqleditor/) will do what you want.

Comment: It seems to have the same problem I had with MySQLWorkbench, the relation between the tables is not displayed.

Answer (score 6):

This http://code.google.com/p/database-diagram/ will reverse engineer your database. Just do an export 'structure only' then paste the SQL into the tool.

Comment: Does not connect the foreign keys (mysql), simply displays the tables with values, and does not allow for a greater screen to fit them all together.

Answer (score 6):

Try [MySQL Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mysql/maestro/). 
Works great for me.

Answer (score 4):

I believe [DB Designer](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/) does something like that.  And I think they even have a free version.

*edit*
Never mind.  Michael's link is much better.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL Workbench worked like a charm.

I just backed up database structure to SQL script and used it in "Create EER Model From SQL Script" of MWB 5.2.37 for Windows.

Answer (score 4):

In MySql Workbench (6.0) its possible generate one diagram based on tables created.
For that you should access to the tools bar, press **Model** and forward **Create Diagram from Catalog Objects** and done!

Answer (score 3):

[Visual Paradigm for UML 9.0](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/editions/community.jsp)

It's awesome I used to work with mysql bench but for big databases (something like more than 300 tables) won't work very well but visual paradigm reverse database works so much better

Comment: Which edition of VP do you have? I have an old copy of v7 but in that version the reverse engineering is only in the (expensive!) enterprise edition.

Comment: Can I generate the diagram from a live database using the community edition?

Answer (score 3):

phpMyAdmin has what you are looking for (for many years now):
It takes a small bit of configuration, but gives you additional benefits too:
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#pmadb

Answer (score 3):

Try out [Vertabelo](http://www.vertabelo.com/)!

It's an online database modeler that supports reverse enginnering.

Just create free of charge [Vertabelo](http://www.vertabelo.com/) account, [import an existing database into Vertabelo](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/reverse-engineering) and voila - your database is in Vertabelo!

It supports following databases:

- PostgreSQL,
- MySQL,
- Oracle,
- IBM DB2,
- HSQLDB,
- MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The "Reverse Engineer Database" mode in Workbench is only part of the paid version, not the free one.

Comment: If this was true, it is no longer.

Comment: It works fine on a fresh, free copy of Workbench downloaded today.

Comment: Yeah, it works in the free version, but since it is fairly opinionated about modifying the schema for certain types of relationships so it is not as useful as you might think for documenting an existing schema that does not follow its conventions.

Comment: I am not sure where to find the sql bench version with reverse engineering tab, as per link it is supported on commercial version only not on community  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-data-modeling-menus.html
:(

Answer (score 0):

Try [SchemaBank](http://schemabank.com). They support reverse engineering too.

Comment: seems to be discontinued

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tool that generates relational diagrams from MySQL (on Windows at the moment).
I have used it on a database with 400 tables.
If the diagram is too big for a single diagram, it gets broken down into smaller ones. So you will probably end up with multiple diagrams and you can navigate between them by right clicking. It is all explained in the link below. The tool is free (as in free beer), the author uses it himself on consulting assignments, and lets other people use it.
http://www.scmlite.com/Quick%20overview

Comment: Currently that domain does not exist

Comment: @dstudeba, this project is now located here:https://github.com/ludoaubert/linkedboxdraw