# What tool can I use to build a nicely-formatted SQL DB diagram on a Mac?

Tags: mysql, database, erd

I need to create an entity relationship diagram for a MySQL database. It doesn't need to be automatically generated or anything, and I don't have foreign keys defined anyway.

I could swear that I once used a tool that would display the relationships between fields, but this old screenshot from MS Access is the closest I've been able to find to what I'm trying to do (source: http://acdrupal.evergreen.edu/files/studycenter/database_entity_relationship_diagram.jpg).

[image: MS Access Entity Relationship Diagram]

Can anyone name an app (preferably for Macs) that can be used to build this kind of diagram? I've tried several of the popular ones - ArgoUML, OmniGraffle, MySQL Workbench - but it doesn't seem that any of them will show those relationship lines from one specific field to another. Instead, they have a generic one-to-one or many-to-one line that goes to the table, but not the specific field.

Comment: does this help you out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql

Comment: I posted earlier about MySQL workbench, sorry about that too tired and not reading the questions right... now I see that you did try it... time to sleep. I removed my answer, sorry for the clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.malcolmhardie.com/sqleditor/

This looks like it supports it if I understand what you need

Answer (score 0):

i like Visio for these drawings.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (literally today, 2023-12-06) [JetBrains’ IDEs](https://www.jetbrains.com/products/#type=ide-vs) such as IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm, RubyMine, can do this. It’s pretty good too. NB: I think the feature might only available in the “pro” editions of these IDEs.