# How do I enlarge an EER Diagram in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I am working on a moderately complex schema in MySQL Workbench, and the single page of the EER diagram is now full up. Does anyone know how to enlarge it to two or more pages?

Answer (score 469, accepted):

On the Model pull-down there is an option Diagram Properties and Size, which allows the size of the diagram to be changed.

Comment: Then ,you can also export a single page pdf. I prefer watching at the db as a big picture...

Comment: Dear MySQL, why this option is so hard to find? It should be displayed near the zoom tool.

Comment: This option is greyed out for me :(

Comment: or just expand/contract it automatically like visio does.

Comment: pull-down?  A more popular name is `menu`

Comment: @ACV, I was traumatised by exposure to X/Motif at an impressionable age.

Answer (score 181):

ER Diagram -> Model -> Diagram Properties and Size...

[image: Menu access]

[image: grid size]

---

[image: Menu access - windows]

[image: grid size - windows]

Comment: Crap! I totally forgot about workbench, how long has it been around? I still use and download the GUI tools!

Comment: This option is not there in new version of mysql workbench6.2

Comment: @RNKushwaha I use Mysql Workbench 6.2 and I have this option. Please try again.

Comment: I use mysql wb in window at home its there but in ubuntu its not.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I use Yosemite.

Comment: Its there but its disabled.

Comment: Finally I got the solution, Its not under model menu but in Arrange->model menu in ubuntu

Comment: @d.danailov thank you for sharing the screenshot, this really helped me.

Answer (score 27):

If the "Diagram Properties and Size..." option is grayed out, do the following:

1. **Save your work**, as this may crash Workbench;
2. Go to Model > Model Options;
3. Choose the "Diagram" tab;
4. Uncheck "Use defaults from global settings..." at the bottom;
5. Confirm "Ok".  This may crash Workbench, depending on the version and/or operating system.
6. Either way, "Model > Diagram Properties and Size..." should now be enabled, even if you had to reopen Workbench.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the already told "diagram propertys" settings - where everything is measured in pages and where you can't enter float values to make slightly smaller or bigger. But you can change the page size itself: `File->Page Setup`

[image]

Answer (score 8):

by the way, if you want a large number of schemas to display correctly, you need to increase the size of the canvas AND zoom out BEFORE running "Auto Layout". if you increase the canvas size enough and zoom out enough all the tables will be spaced apart nicely.

Answer (score 3):

If you are under Linux, and it is hanging when you try to elarge the canvas size, try zoomming out to the smallest view possible before changing the canvas properties.

Worked for me.

Regards,
Leo.

Answer (score 2):

If option "Diagram Properties and Size" is disabled (grayed out) 
You can try to run MysqlWorkbench with sudo

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql-workbench
```

I am not good at linux, there should be some miss-configuration leading to this. So I'am only saying that this resolved the problem for me.

(system info 
MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Linux/Unix version 6.2.3  revision 12312 build 2280 (64 bit)
Configuration Directory: /home/arsen/.mysql/workbench
Data Directory: /usr/share/mysql-workbench
Cairo Version: 1.13.1
OS: Linux 3.13.0-76-generic
CPU: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU           @ 2.40GHz (1596.000MHz) - 5,83GiB RAM
Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
)