# Customize grid size in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

My grid in MySQL Workbench isn't wide enough, is it possible for me to customize the width?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22268035/682754

Model -> Diagram Properties and Size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enlarge an EER Diagram in MySQL Workbench?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933000/how-do-i-enlarge-an-eer-diagram-in-mysql-workbench)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to File>Page Setup and you can get a bigger grid by selecting B4 (250mm x 353mm).

Comment: Or whatever your preference of size is from the drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

For the newer versions you should go to `Edit -> Preferences -> Fonts` and then find `Resulset Grid` and choose the size you want.