# How to add a new page in MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench

I want to add a new page in MySql Workbench. How this is possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Do you want to split your diagram over multiple pages or add more space to a diagram (by defining a larger area) or add a new diagram?

Comment: Yes I want to split diagram to multiple pages to add more tables. How is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enlarge an EER Diagram in MySQL Workbench?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933000/how-do-i-enlarge-an-eer-diagram-in-mysql-workbench)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Open your model, go to Model -> Diagram Properties and Size.. In the dialog that opens either drag your size with the mouse (in the grid) or enter new values in the text boxes below that grid.

Answer (score 3):

1.Go to **Model > Diagram Properties and Size** [image]
2.Select the pages that you need [image]