# How do I create tables and relations using an ER-diagram?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have attached a diagram I got it from here only...My question is: How do I convert that to a table form and how do I add relationships between tables according to the diagram? Any samples will be a great help! [image: ER-Model]

Comment: What tool generated the diagram?  Most of these things should also be able to generate the needed SQL.

Comment: An explanation of database design principles is beyond what SO is designed for.  If you have no idea how to approach this problem you need more help than you are going to get here.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reading the [Wikipedia article on ER-diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER_diagram) (your graphic is called an **E**ntity-**R**elationship diagramm)

And as Jim Garrison said in the comment

> An explanation of database design
>   principles is beyond what SO is
>   designed for.

If you have some experience with databases, the Wikipedia article may help you. If you still need to create a database (is this homework??), take a look at [tools to assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql) you. Otherwise, make yourself familiar with the principles of DB design.