# C#/Sql managment studio -> generate ER diagram for latex (PDF)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, latex, erd

Just like in the title. Is it possible to generate ER diagram that can by convertert to latex file (or text file) for printing that in PDF (maybe some dll) ? OR how can i build that kind of diagram dynamically ? Got any suggestions ? Mine "looks" like that:

I need to extract from database all needed tables names and all column names for that tables. Then need to create relations, and thats the part that looks pretty hard. Could you give me some advice or maybe, like i said before there is an easier way to generate simple ER diagram from database.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this service](http://diagram.ly) . But it`s for "handmading", not automatic generation

Comment: and take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql)

Comment: thx for the tip but i need to do it automaticly ;). I need to create code that will generate that kind of diagram form a database to latex print pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Your title includes "Sql management studio" so I'm assuming that's fair game.

You can use SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) to connect to your DB, then navigate to the database you want, and create a new Database Diagram.  The Database Diagram is very customizable.  Each table you add to the diagram can be right-clicked on for a context menu, and using Table View you can modify what fields to display.  And if you right click in the designer you can show page breaks that will occur when printing.

As for printing to PDF, I'd suggest just using the standard print functionality in SSMS, and print to PDF using some tool that prints to PDF, like Cute PDF Writer or Office's built in PDF printing support.  You may have issues getting all your tables and their relationships on one sheet of paper, but you'd probably have that issue in most tools.