# Tool for table_schema and table_name relationship

Tags: mysql, profiling, data-profiling

Do you know any tools for profiling,to see the structure and relationship of each tables inside the db? it is look like this one :

See screenShot below,

[image]

[For **bigger resolution**, Please click here.](http://www.geneontology.org/images/diag-godb-er.jpg)

Thanks In advance.

Any help much more appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench is what youre looking for

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: i am using putty / secure crt..how can i configure this?

Comment: You connect directly on 3306 or whatever your mysql port is. Need to have user access from the appropriate external ip, unless on the same machine as the db then just use localhost

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), if I remember correctly it has a function, which can do this (reverse engineer database or something similar).

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Database Designer for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-designer.html) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio).

*Database Designer is a powerful visual design tool for database development that allows you to build a clear and effective database structure visually and to see the complete picture representing all the tables, foreign key relations between them, views, and stored routines of your database on database diagrams.*

Answer (score 0):

[Toad for MySQL](http://toadformysql.com/index.jspa) has a Database Diagram feature allowing you to create such drawings from existing databases.

Answer (score 0):

[SchemaCrawler for MySQL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/schemacrawler/files/SchemaCrawler%20-%20MySQL/) is a free command-line tool that diagrams databases. SchemaCrawler is particularly useful when diagramming large and complex schemas, since it can diagram tables based on the results of regular expression searches of table and column names.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler