# create erd from sql in dbschema

Tags: mysql, db-schema

Can anyone describe how to create an erd from an sql file with DbSchema?  I have not found what begins the process.

I also tried using MySQL workbench.  Upon choosing the file, a window opens indicating 'Reverse engineering and importing objects from script...', but nothing ever happens; no progress is ever indicated in the message log at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used `MySQL WorkBench` and I loved it. You probably providing something wrong in the Reverse Engineering process. [SchemaSPY](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) is a good tool as well. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql) too.