# Can you make an inheritance diagram in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, inheritance, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to make an ERD involving inheritances. is it possible that I could make one in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql

Comment: I'm afraid that's not like my question. I'm using MySQL Workbench right now and I'm just wondering if I could put some inheritance symbols in it. (e.g. Bulldog extends Dog, Cat extends Feline, Lemonade extends Beverage)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, visualizing inheritance (as it is part of the [EER modeling super and subclass idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)) is not possible with MySQL Workbench. We decided not to include features that you cannot represent in MySQL.

Comment: OK thank you very much. Guess I'll just draw it manually for now.