# how to convert mysql database to class diagram

Tags: mysql, class-diagram

I  have a mysql database and now I want to convert it into class diagram. Is there any way to convert mysql database to class diagram? I'm using MySql Workbench for design database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2495/3783143

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ediardo answer is almost correct but ediardo missed important part. You must check on the 'Place imported objects on a diagram' in the Select Object section. Then click Execute.

Answer (score 12):

1. Open workbench and create a new Model
2. Add a new Diagram
3. Click on Database -> Reverse Engineer (Ctrl + R)
4. Fill connection options and follow the steps
5. You will see all the entities and their relationships (if any)

Comment: I have the ER. I need Class diagram

Comment: For mac cmd+R is the shortcut got Reverse Engineer, instead of ctrl+R

Comment: this is not for the class diagramm