# How to spot the relationship in RDBMS?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, relational-database, relationship

I was studying about relationships in RDBMS.I have understood the basic concept behind mapping relation ship,but I am not able to spot them.

The three possibilities :

1. one to many(Most common) requires a PK - FK relationsip.Two tables involved
2. many to many(less common) requires a junction table.Three tables Involved
3. one to one(very rare). One table involved.

When I begin a project,I am not  able to separate the first two conditions and I am not clear in my head.
Examples when I study help for a brief moment,but not when I need to put these principles in to practice.

This is the place where most begineers falter.
*How can I spot these relationships.Is there a simpler way?*

Comment: Can you give example of what you mean?

Comment: Which of the options to use is so clear that I don't understand why you cannot spot it. Please, show an example that makes you crazy.

Comment: It is very general question.I am sorry I cant give you an example,but I can elaborate about the question.When we start working on a project we create multiple tables.Though these tables are related in some way,I cannot spot it.I am looking for a very general answer so that i can atleast plot all my relationsips on a single sheet of paper.Any general idea is ok.

Comment: I'd suggest just creating an ER diagram, this should show your relationships in a simple layout. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2488/1048425) for generating an ER diagram in MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't look at relationships from a technical perspective. Use analogies and real-life examples when trying to envision relationships in your head.

For example, let's say we have a library database.
A library must have **books**.

## M:M

Each `Book` may have been written by multiple `Authors` and each `Author` may have written multiple `Books`. Thus it is a **many-to-many** relationship which will reflect into 3 tables in the database.

## 1:M

Each `Book` must also have a `Publisher`, but a `Book` may only have one `Publisher` and a `Publisher` can publish many `Books`. Thus it is a **one-to-many** relationship and it reflects with the `PublisherId` being referenced in the `Books` table.

A simple analogy like this one explains relationships to their core. When you try to look at them through a technical lens you're only making it harder on yourself. What's actually difficult is applying real world data scenarios when constructing your database.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason you are not getting the answers that you need is because of the way you are framing the question.  Instead of asking “How do I spot the correct type of relationship between entities”, think about “How do my functional needs dictate what relationship to implement”.  Database design doesn’t drive the function; it’s the functional needs that drive the relationships you need to implement.

When designing a database structure, you need to identify all the entities.  Entities are all the facts that you want to store: lists of things like book titles, invoices, countries, dog species, etc.  Then to identify your relationships, you have to consider the types of questions you will want to ask your database.  It takes a bit of forward thinking sometimes… just because nobody is asking the question **now** doesn’t mean that it might not ever be asked.  So you can’t ask the universe “what is the relationship between these lists of facts?” because there is no definitive answer.   You define the universe… I only want to know answers to these types of questions; therefore I need to use this type of relationship.

Let’s examine an example relation between two common entities:  a table of customers and a table of store locations.  There is no “correct” way to relate these entities without first defining what you need to know about them.  Let’s say you work for a retailer and you want to give a customer a default store designation so they can see products on the website that their local store has in stock.  This only requires a one-to-many relationship between a store and the customer.  Designing the relationship this way ensures that one store can have many customers as their default and each customer can only have one default store.  To implement this relationship is as easy as adding a `DefaultStore` field to your `Customer` table as a foreign key that links to the primary key of the `Store` table.

The same two entities above might have alternate requirements for the relationship definition in a different context.  Let’s say that I need to be able to give the customer the opportunity to select a list of favorite stores so that they can query about in stock information about all of them at once.  This requires a many-to-many relationship because you want one customer to be able to relate to many stores and each store can also relate to many customers.  To implement a many-to-many relationship requires a little more overhead because you will have to create a separate table to define the relationship links, but you get this additional functionality.  You might call your relationship table something like `CustomerStoreFavorites` and would have as its primary key as the combined primary keys from each of the entities: `(CustomerID, StoreID)`.  You could also add attributes to the relationship, like possibly a `LastOrderDate` field to specify the last date that the customer ordered something from a particular store.

You could technically define both types of relationships for the same two entities.  As an example: maybe you need to give the customer the option to select a default store, but you also need to be able to record the last date that a customer ordered something from a particular store.  You could implement the `DefaultStore` field on the `Customer` table with the foreign key to the `Store` table **and also** create a relationship table to track all the stores that a customer has ordered from.

If you had some weird situation where every customer had their own store, then you wouldn’t even need to create two tables for your entities because you can fit all the attributes for both the customer and the store into one table.

In short, the way you determine which type of relationship to implement is to ask yourself what questions you will need to ask the database.  The way you design it will restrict the relational data you can collect as well as the queries you can ask.  If I design a one-to-many relationship from the store to the customer, I won’t be able to ask questions about all the stores that each customer has ordered from unless I can get to that information though other relationships.  For example, I could create an entity called "purchases" which has a one-to-many relationship to the customer and store.  If each purchase is defined to relate to one customer and one store, now I can query “what stores has this customer ordered from?”  In fact with this structure I am able to capture and report on a much richer source of information about all of the customer's purchases at any store.  So you also need to consider the context of all the other relationships in your database to decide which relationship to implement between two particular entities.

There is no magic formula, so it just takes practice, experience, and a little creativity.  ER Diagrams are a great way to get your design out of your head and onto paper so that you can analyze your design and ensure that you can get the right types of questions answered.  There are also a lot of books and resources to learn about database architecture.  One good book I learned a lot from was “Database System Concepts” by Abraham Silberschatz and Henry Korth.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have two tables A and B. Consider an entry from A and think of how many entries from B it could possibly be related with at most: only one, or more? Then consider an entry from B and think of how many entries in A it could be related with.

Some examples:

Table A: Mothers, Table B: Children. Each child has only one mother but a mother may have one or more children. Mothers and Children have a **one-to-many** relationship.

Table A: Doctors, Table B: Patients. Each patient may be visiting one or more doctors and each doctor treats one or more patients. So they have a **many-to-many** relationship.

Answer (score 2):

An example of one to one:
LicencePlate to Vehicle. One licence plate belongs to one vehicle and one vehicle has one licence plate.