# How do I see the EER Model for an mySQL database I have created using DDL

Tags: mysql, ddl, table-relationships, eer-model

I've created a new schema/database in DDL query thing in MySQL Work Bench. (I hope I explain myself well enough since I can't post images without 10 Rep apparently... Like the code below sort of stuff).

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `bicycle_rental`;
USE `bicycle_rental`;

CREATE TABLE `Bicycles`
(
    `id_bicycles` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `bicycle_details` varchar(45),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_bicycles`)
);
```

But I can't figure out how to make it appear in the visual table like an EER model so I can see the relationships and all that.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Try [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wfy8rdhXyWw)? There should be an option to Generate ER Diagram. Also what version of MySQL Work Bench do you have?

Comment: Version 6.1.6.11834 Build 1642.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql#answer-24695641)

Comment: That first video link was very helpful. If you convert your comment to an answer i can Solve it for you, if thats how this thing works.

Comment: Added as answer. Let us know if you need anymore help :) if you have a different question altogether, feel free to make a new question. If it's related to this, simply comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL Workbench when you fire the application, there should be a way for you to create a new EER Model from an existing database. Once you choose that option, you should be able to go through a wizard that guides you through the process.

Here is a helpful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wfy8rdhXyWw).