# Good method for database schema reverse engineering

Tags: mysql, database, schema, reverse-engineering, myisam

I need to know a good procedure to create a database table model from a MyISAM -engine database. Using a wizard -like software solution seems to be out of question as MyISAM lacks foreign keys. JOINs define the connection between tables.

The database itself is quite a mess, having several multiple to multiple connections between tables and even references to same table.

I am very new into database schema creation having only studied basic course before attempting into this.

My best guess was to pull a listing of all tables and start to read source code from related php project with Netbeans. I know this method will be slow, and maybe only change to do this - but is there any good method into doing this?

I am planning to use MS Visio for collecting results there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Generate Database Diagram MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488/auto-generate-database-diagram-mysql)

Comment: I find that such tools discover only a little of the structure.  Understanding the data and the code is still necessary.

Comment: @ThomasG this is a different topic as i am looking for methods, not straightforward tools. Tools will be used but i am more curious about the things that need to be taken into consideration - more like the philosophy and methods about this. Sorry about my english.